# Checks if two arrays have elements in the same order

Tags: java, arrays

How can I check whether two arrays (cyclic) has the same elements in the same order.
For examples let's take array [1,2,3,4].

The test should return true for [2,3,4,1], [3,4,1,2], [4,1,2,3] but not for [1,3,2,4], [1,4,2,3] or [1,2,3,5].

My initial approach was to find first match - one element from each array that are equal - and considering these two elements as initial elements of their respective arrays I compared rest of the arrays' elements on one-by-one basis.

Is there any better way?
Thank you.

Comment: Are duplicates allowed? With no duplicates it's rather trivial, with duplicates is still trivial but a little less obvious.

Comment: Your approach is a good start, but it would fail for `[1,2,1,3]` and `[1,3,1,2]`. Just treat the first as an endless repetition and do a substring search in it for the second (limited to indices 0 through N)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an array is cyclic then `array+array` has the the whole array of another part. 
For example:

```
 [2 3 4 1] append [2 3 4 1] = [2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1]
                                    |-------|
```

as you can see `[1 2 3 4]` is "somewhere" in the appending of the same array twice.

So by this logic you can do a `O(n*m)` operation that checks every case to see if it is a match (n being array1 and m being array2):

```
 //array1 has [2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1]
 //array2 has [1 2 3 4]
 boolean check = false;
 for(int i = 0; i < array1.length(); i++) {
   for(int j; j < array2.length(); j++) {
      if((i+j) <= array1.length()) {
        if(array1[i+j] == array2[j])
            check = true;
        else
            check = false;
      }
   }
   if(check)
       return true; // returns true if all array2 == some part of array1
 }
 return false;
```

You can also check out the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) to improve on this. Its for string matching, but the same logic can be applied here.

The basic idea is having a lookup table of array2 and being able to "skip" values you know you don't have to check again.

```
1   2   3  4  5  6
3   4   5
^-------^  lookup table sees that the offset is 3 to match array2[0] with array1[2]

    1   2   3  4  5  6
 skip to--->3  4  5
    would be the next iteration
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation really helped me and was exactly what I needed. Out of curiosity, my teacher mentioned that there is special property of cyclic arrays that makes it possible to check this equality in linear time. Would you know by any chance anything about this?

Comment: Are there any duplicate values in the original array? And actually this alorithm is not 0(n^2) I think I made a mistake it is actually 0(n*m) where n is the first array and m is the second array. As n increases in size amortized time goes to 0(n). I also added something to the bottom to make this algorithm faster

Comment: In my problem there shouldn't be any duplicates. But in the problem that my teacher mentioned, I am not sure. He said 2 cyclic arrays in general. The improved algorithms is supposed to be O(3n).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried like this and it works:

```
    int a[] = {2,3,4,1};
    int b[] = {3,4,1,2};  // return true for these input

    boolean check = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int tmp = b[0];
        System.arraycopy(b, 1, b, 0, b.length - 1);
        b[b.length - 1] = tmp;
        if (Arrays.equals(a, b)) {
            check = true;
            System.out.println("Output: " + Arrays.equals(a, b));
        }
    }
    if (!check) {
        System.out.println("Output: false");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume this algorithm can help you.

```
public void test() {
    int[] a1 = {1,2,3,4};
    int[] a2 = {2,3,4,5};
    int[] a3 = {2,3,4,1};
    if (calculateDifference(a1, a2)) {
        System.out.println("a1 has same elements order to a2");
    }
    if (calculateDifference(a1, a3)) {
        System.out.println("a1 has same elements order to a3");
    }
    if (calculateDifference(a2, a3)) {
        System.out.println("a2 has same elements order to a3");
    }
}
private boolean calculateDifference(int[] a1,int[] a2){
    int total = 0;
    boolean match = false;
    if (a1.length != a2.length) {
        return match;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        int a1Num = a1[i];
        int a2Num = a2[i];
        total += a1Num - a2Num;
    }
    if (total == 0) {
        match = true;
    }
    return match;
}
```

Comment: This algorithm doesnt take into account the order of the elements. EG: `calculateDifference(new int[]{1,3,2,4}, new int[]{1,2,3,4})` is `true`. Should be `false`

Comment: Joe said {1,3,2,4} should be false, because it's not in same order.

Answer (score 0):

If no duplicates are allowed you just need to find another element in the second array equal to the first of the first array and check them from there, the solution is O(n):

```
boolean areEquivalent(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
  int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
  for (; i2 < array2.length; ++i2)
    if (array2[i2] == array1[i1])
     break;

  // no element found in common, they can't be equivalent
  if (i2 == array2.length)
    return false;

  for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; ++j)
    if (array1[i1+j] != array2[(i2+j) % array2.length]
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

If duplicates are allowed you must take into account that both `i1` and `i2` could start from different points and try all of them, if the last `for` fails you should change `i1` to start from the second occurrence of the same value and so on. After finishing this you must change `i2` e retry again, so a different approach (like the one proposed by Jay) would work better.